# PHP - How to solve error "using $this when not in object context"?

Tags: php, oop

I've this trait class:

```
trait Example
{
    protected $var;

    private static function printSomething()
    {
        print $var;
    }

    private static function doSomething()
    {
        // do something with $var
    }
}
```

And this class:

```
class NormalClass
{
    use Example;

    public function otherFunction()
    {
        $this->setVar($string);
    }

    public function setVar($string)
    {
        $this->var = $string;
    }
}
```

But i'm getting this error:
`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`.

How can i solve this issue? I can't use properties on a trait class? Or this isn't really a good practice?

Comment: where/how are you calling setvar()? to get that error you'd have to be doing something like `$foo = NormalClass::setVar()` or whatever. and for your printSomething, `$var` would be an undefined local variable.

Comment: @MarcB i've updated my question.

Comment: that doesn't help, now it becomes "how/where are you calling otherFunction()"? You need to show the ENTIRE call chain.

Comment: You probably mean `print static::$var;`, since that method is *static*.  Instance variables aren't going to help you there.

Comment: you are mixing instance-variables (which are part of the instance of a class) with class-variables (static, which are part of the class itself), `$this->var VS. self::$var`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem is connected with differences between class's methods/properties and object's.

1. If you define a property as static - you should access it through your class like classname/`self`/`parent` `::$property`.
2. If not static - then inside static property like `$this->property`.

For example:

```
trait Example   
{
    protected static $var;
    protected $var2;
    private static function printSomething()
    {
        print self::$var;
    }
    private function doSomething()
    {
        print $this->var2;
    }
}
class NormalClass
{
    use Example;
    public function otherFunction()
    {
        self::printSomething();
        $this->doSomething();
    }
    public function setVar($string, $string2)
    {
        self::$var = $string;
        $this->var2 = $string2;
    }
}
$obj = new NormalClass();
$obj -> setVar('first', 'second');
$obj -> otherFunction();
```

Static function printSomething can't access not static propertie $var!
You should define them both not static, or both static.

Comment: @JoSSte please don't add meaningless edits

Answer (score 0):

Using `$this` when not in object context because of this code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
```