# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in - using public only

Tags: php, fatal-error

i am getting error : `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in` line `$stmt_edit = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT userName, userEmail, phone FROM tbl_users WHERE userID =:uid');`  , i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735099/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context-in) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643931/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context) 
& [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053694/php-how-to-solve-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context) and all other google , yahoo links but nothing worked for me, please check below code and help me.

**usr**

```
global $DB_con;
 error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';

 if(isset($_GET['edit_id']) && !empty($_GET['edit_id']))
 {
  $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
  $stmt_edit = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT userName, userEmail, phone FROM tbl_users WHERE userID =:uid');
  $stmt_edit->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
  $edit_row = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  extract($edit_row);
 }
 else
 {
  header("Location: home.php");
 }
```

**dbconfig**

```
<?php
$db = isset($_POST['db']) ? $_POST['db'] : '';
class Database
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "designer3";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "123456";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()

    {   
    global $DB_con;
    $db = isset($_POST['db']) ? $_POST['db'] : '';
        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {

            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

**update**

i tried by  creating new object un user page, but still  it did't worked for me : gave this strange error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepaâ€Œâ€‹re() on a non-object in`

**code**

```
$oDb=new Database();
 $custDb=$oDb->dbConnection();
 $custDb->conn->prepa‌​re('SELECT userName, userEmail, phone FROM tbl_users WHERE userID =:uid');
```

Comment: @Naruto i followed , but didt worked for me

Comment: please tell why downvotes, so that i can correct it.....

Comment: We told you what the issue is in chat already. Please do not abuse Stack Overflow as a live debugging tool. At least try to understand what others have told you now numerous times about the error.

Comment: @Gordon i followed that link &  declared as `$DB_con` , but it didt worked for me

Comment: please check updated question @Gordon i declared as `global $DB_con;` but still not working for me......

Comment: @downvoter : please tell me why downvotes, so that i can correct it.....

Comment: @Gordon as you said, i tried by creating new object, please check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be

```
global $DB_con;
 error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';

 if(isset($_GET['edit_id']) && !empty($_GET['edit_id']))
 {
  $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
  $stmt_edit = $DB_con->conn->prepare('SELECT userName, userEmail, phone FROM tbl_users WHERE userID =:uid');
  $stmt_edit->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
  $edit_row = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  extract($edit_row);
 }
 else
 {
  header("Location: home.php");
 }
```

$this reference to the current object, it's most commonly used in object oriented code.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
Primer: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html

and your dbconfig.php should be

```
<?php
$db = isset($_POST['db']) ? $_POST['db'] : '';
class Database
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "designer3";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "123456";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()

    {   
    global $DB_con;
    $db = isset($_POST['db']) ? $_POST['db'] : '';
        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {

            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        $DB_con=$this->conn;
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: nowi  am getting this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in` for this line : `$stmt_edit = $DB_con->conn->prepare('SELECT userName, userEmail, phone FROM tbl_users WHERE userID =:uid');`

Comment: sorry, i already tried `global $DB_con;` , but it didt worked for me.....

Comment: you didnt create any object for class Database and you are trying to access its function then it wont work you need to assign connection context to global variable and call method via it. or create new object $oDb=new Database();$custDb=$oDb->dbConnection() and call method like $custDb->conn->prepare('SELECT userName, userEmail, phone FROM tbl_users WHERE userID =:uid');

Comment: try this $custDb=$oDb->dbConnection(); and call method like $custDb->conn->prepare('SELECT userName, userEmail, phone FROM tbl_users WHERE userID =:uid');

Comment: dbconfig : http://pastebin.com/sjV6A1Y9 &   editform : http://pastebin.com/pPezGzmi , now getting error as : `Fatal error: Call to a member function dbConnection() on a non-object in` looks like i done something wrong ?

Comment: your full code is here, it should work. $oDb=new Database();$custDb=$oDb->dbConnection();$custDb->conn->prepare('SELECT userName, userEmail, phone FROM tbl_users WHERE userID =:uid');

Comment: i added your code in editform.php file, now i am getting this error  : `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepaâ€Œâ€‹re() on a non-object in `

Comment: editform : http://pasted.co/aeedf016 , dbconfig : http://pasted.co/fe2456d3

Comment: $pdo is undefined. You're not declaring it inside the function, and it isn't being passed in as an argument.

You need to either pass it in (good), or define it in the global namespace and make it available to your function by placing global $pdo at the top (bad).

Comment: i tried this code : `global $conn;` under `public function` , but still it did't worked for me....